# Dart encodeFull issue

Tags: flutter, dart, uri

When i encode an uri from integer to string. Dart put this %E2%80%8B value before number. What is the reason? Why the dart put this value before number? I can't send parameters from url like that.

```
const number = 15;
String uri = Uri.encodeFull("https://google.com/${number}");
print(uri);
```

i got this output https://google.com/15%E2%80%8B   why ?? check the link there is a space end of uri. When it work like this i can't call the api because its not a integer value.

İs it a bug or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%E2%80%8B` represents a sequence of hexadecimal bytes `E2`, `80`, `8B`.  That sequence corresponds to the UTF-8 representation of the [Unicode "zero width space" character (U+200B)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm).

I suspect that you copied and pasted your string from somewhere and inadvertently included an invisible Unicode character.  Deleting and retyping the last portion of your `"https://google.com/${number}"` string literal should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please add more info, I Have tested your code it's behaving normally.

```
 var number=1234;
 var k=Uri.encodeFull("https://google.com/${number}");
```

Output: https://google.com/1234